# Labels in Java - bad practice?

Tags: java, label

Why using labels in Java is a bad practice? I cant find a reason. All explanations - you shouldn't use it just because you shouldn't.

Comment: This is the best explanation I could find:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185944/java-labels-to-be-or-not-to-be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to read code containing `break`s to a label. Also, a label can be accidentally moved, or code inserted at an incorrect location with respect to a label. The compiler is not able to warn you of these effects since the code remains syntactically valid.

Code that's difficult to read is difficult to maintain. Bugs will inevitably creep in.

Other control structures (`break`, `continue`, `while`, `for`, etc.) don't suffer from this.

Note that a `switch` to a label doesn't suffer from these effects either: the structure of a `switch` block is well-defined.

The most sensible alternative to breaking out of a nested loop is to recast the code to a function and use `return`. You also get the added benefit of being able (potentially) to return a value back to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are referring to break and continue labeled.

The problem is that labeled **break** (and continue) is a construct of imperative languages that is absolutely **not related to Object Oriented**.

In Object Oriented programs the flows can be easily understood. It is not possible to jump from a part of code to another part of code, you can only call a method or continue current code or exit the current block of code.

**Jumping from position to position is a probable point of break** for your application where bugs can easily happens. Jumping creates what is called *[spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)*

Comment: This has always been a paradox to me. Everybody seem to agree that one should not use labels, but in a lot of frameworks, as well as in JDK code, labels are used quite a lot...

Comment: The problem is that if a language offer the possibility to do something somebody will always use it. Somebody will use it with common sense, some other not.

Comment: But the usual advice when one learns best practices is to take a look at some big frameworks code. Does the fact that some big frameworks use labels make it a bad advice ?

Comment: If you need for example to exit from two nested loops use a labeled break is a possibility. But frameworks and libraries are designed by humans. So some of them can have design errors, just as an example java.util.Date is a mutable class and often this is considered a bad design decision.

Answer (score 1):

Labelled breaks (and breaks, in a smaller way) are a more-modern equivalent to the old GOTO statements of older languages (FORTRAN, COBOL, Basic). Goto statements were found to be much more liable to contain an error than all other kinds of statements combined -- the study I'm remembering measured it as 9 times more likely. This gave rise to the "structured programming" movement in the 70s, and the banning of the goto statement from some software shops at the time.

It is more important to be able to read code easily than to be able to write it without restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are fine to break out of nested for-loops. I'd suggest to put the nested loops in a separate method and then break out with `return`.

The problem is that the complex flows of processing becomes really hard to follow.